# overflow: scroll with position: absolute parent prevent scroll

Tags: html, css

I have a container div .filter that has a max-height of 200px. Within this I have a list with lots of items, which I want to make scroll within the parent. This works fine, however I also want to use a pseudo element to position at the bottom of .filter, to create a gradient effect into which the long list scrolls behind. However, I can't get this psuedo element to remain fixed to the bottom of .filter, as it currently scrolls with the rest of the content?

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<span class="filter">
  <span class="filter-list">
    <h3>List item</h3>
    <h3>List item</h3>
    <h3>List item</h3>
    <!-- List items continue here -->
  </span>
</span>
```

**SCSS**

```
.filter {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-y: scroll;

    // Create gradient to indicate further items in list
    &:after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000000, transparent);
    }

    .filter-list {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gnuoja3z/5/)

Comment: Good point, but that doesn't rectify the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need to set `height` of `.filter-list` instead of `.filter`
- set `position: relative` or `absolute` to `.filter`

```css
.filter {
  width: 300px;
  position: relative; /* You can set to absolute */
}
.filter:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 15px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000, transparent);
}
.filter .filter-list {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter">
  <div class="filter-list">
    <h3>List item</h3>
    <h3>List item</h3>
    <h3>List item</h3>
    <h3>List item</h3>
    <h3>List item</h3>
    <h3>List item</h3>
    <!-- List items continue here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle with `scss` [here](http://jsfiddle.net/npmv70xq/6/)

Comment: Awesome! This is one of the only solutions I've found that a) doesn't require the container to be ``position: absolute`` and b) works correctly when the contents is split into multiple columns with ``columns: 250px 3``.

Comment: @kmoser Glad it helped you :)